# Crackling from WebAudio oscillators on browser interaction

Tags: javascript, audio

This code does what I want, which is gradually change the volume of two waveforms. However, I am experiencing quite a lot of crackling, namely whenever I interact with the browser in some way (eg: when switching tabs). Can anyone explain why this is happening, and if it can be fixed, how?

Thanks. A working demo is here:  https://jsfiddle.net/50cepayr/1/

(Btw - as far as I know, this is not the same as the "ugly click" problem of starting and stopping audio (such as is described here: http://alemangui.github.io/blog//2015/12/26/ramp-to-value.html)... the crackling sound is different and the unrelated to starting/stopping.)

```
function getRandArb(min, max) {
   return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var context = new AudioContext();
var frequencyValue = 220;

var oscSaw = context.createOscillator();
oscSaw.type = "sawtooth";
oscSaw.frequency.value = frequencyValue;
oscSaw.start(context.currentTime);
var gainSaw = context.createGain();
gainSaw.gain.value = 0.5*Math.random();     console.log("saw",gainSaw.gain.value);
oscSaw.connect(gainSaw);

var oscTri = context.createOscillator();
oscTri.type = "triangle";
oscTri.frequency.value = frequencyValue;
oscTri.start(context.currentTime);
var gainTri = context.createGain();
gainTri.gain.value = 3*Math.random();       console.log("tri",gainTri.gain.value);
oscTri.connect(gainTri);

var gainOscSum = context.createGain();
gainOscSum.gain.value = 1;
gainSaw.connect(gainOscSum);
gainTri.connect(gainOscSum);
gainOscSum.connect(context.destination);

function changeGainsSmooth(){                   
    var newGainSaw = 0.5*Math.random();
    gainSaw.gain.setTargetAtTime(newGainSaw, context.currentTime, 1.9)  
    console.log("saw",gainSaw.gain.value);
    var newGainTri = 3*Math.random();
    gainTri.gain.setTargetAtTime(newGainTri, context.currentTime, 1.9)      
    console.log("tri",gainTri.gain.value);
}

setInterval(changeGainsSmooth,2000);



https://jsfiddle.net/50cepayr/
```

Comment: This also happens if you unplug headphones and thank you for the link on getting rid of the click sound

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue? I'm experiencing the same thing - on heavy browser updates I hear the crackling sound

Comment: @K.Rice My understanding at this point is that it is a simply a performance issue. Browsers are not optimized for audio and so when there is other load, this happens. A better machine helps. However my knowledge of the actual audio mechanics under the hood is limited, so take this with a grain of salt.